# Map value to type to avoid switch statement in C++

Tags: c++, templates, switch-statement

Recently I faced a problem that I could not manage on my own. Let's assume that we receive some bytes from network by function:

```
vector<char> receive ();
```

When I get bytes I know precisely what are for example first 10 bytes, and how to interpret them. Rest of the message is connected with value being used in the Id (these 10 bytes). So, for example it can be expressed like this:

```
auto bytes = receive ();
Id id = get_id (bytes);

switch (id) { 
    case Id::Message1:
    {
        Message1 message = convert_bytes<Message1> (bytes);
        notify (message);
        break;
    }

    case Id::Message2:
    {
        Message2 message = convert_bytes<Message2> (bytes);
        notify (message);
        break;
    }
    ...

    case Id::MessageN:
    {
        MessageN message = convert_bytes<MessageN> (bytes);
        notify (message);
        break;
    }
}
```

As you see, each case section differs from others only with Message Id and type of Message.

My question is: **Is there any possibility to map Id value to the specific type of Message to make above code simpler and not to use switch statement?**

```
auto bytes = receive ();
Id id = get_id (bytes);

// Here some magic retrieval of Message type based on Id value and invoking 
// appropriate convert_bytes specialization
// auto message = convert_bytes<get_message_type(id)> (bytes); (Y)
```

Of course (Y) is wrong, but maybe you know some other way of doing the concept.

I know that this logic of connection Id value to the type has to be implemented somewhere, but it would be much simpler just to connect Id value to the type than writing case section for each Message type.

I know also, that I probably could do something like this:

```
class Base {};
class Message1 : Base {}
...
class MessageN : Base {}

vector<pair<Id, Base*>> vec;
```

but I don't know if this is good/efficient way since I should use dynamic_cast each time I would like to convert Base* to MessageX*.

I tried to do some wrapper class with tuple and initializer_list, something like this:

```
struct Message1 { int x; };
struct Message2 { double z; };

enum class Id { Message1, Message2 };

template <typename Id_type, typename ... Types>
class Wrapper { 
    public:
        Wrapper (tuple<Types ...> t, const initializer_list<Id_type>& il) : tpl (t), ids (il) {


        }

       MessageType_depended_on_id get_message (Id id, vector<char> bytes); // (X)


    private:
        tuple<Types ...> tpl;
        vector<Id_type> ids;
};

tuple<Message1, Message2> tpl;
Wrapper<Id, Message1, Message2> wrapper (tpl, {Id::Message1, Id::Message2});
```

(X) But there is no way to specify member function type depended on the id value, or am I missing something?

My last thought was to implement each case section in template specialization, something like this:

```
template <Id id> 
class Type_retriever {};

template <>
class Type_retriever<Id::Message1> {
    public:
        static Message1 get_msg (const vector<char>& bytes) { 
            cout << "Message1" << endl;
            return convert_bytes<Message1> (bytes);
        }
};

template <>
class Type_retriever<Id::Message2> {
    public:
        static Message2 get_msg (const vector<char>& bytes) { 
            cout << "Message2" << endl;
            return convert_bytes<Message2> (bytes);
        }
};

template <typename Type>
void notify (Type message) { }

auto bytes = receive ();
auto id = get_id (bytes);
notify (Type_retriever<id>::get_msg (bytes));
```

But this will not compile because the value of ‘id’ is not usable in a constant expression (gcc) which is understandable why this can not compile.

If you have any suggestion, it would be great.

Comment: You are looking for the factory pattern. You don't map values to types, but rather values to functions/objects that perform deserialization. Mapping can be done by std::map. Look at other serialization libraries/frameworks for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the `switch` statement using a registration/plugin mechanism.

Interface for registering functions and using them:

```
typedef void (*MessageDispatcher)(const vector<byte>& bytes);

void registerMessageDispatcher(Id id, MessageDispatcher dispatcher);

void dispatchMessage(Id id, const vector<byte>& bytes);
```

In the implementation:

```
static std::map<Id, MessageDispatcher> messageDispatcherMap;

void registerMessageDispatcher(Id id, MessageDispatcher dispatcher)
{
   messageDispatcherMap[id] = dispatcher;
}

void dispatchMessage(Id id, const vector<byte>& bytes)
{
   std::map<Id, MessageDispatcher>::iterator iter = messageDispatcherMap.find(id);
   if ( iter == messageDispatcherMap.end() )
   {
      // Deal with the error condition.
      return;
   }

   // Dispatch the message.
   iter->second(bytes);

}
```

Create functions for various message types.

```
void dispatchMessage1(const vector<byte>& bytes)
{
   Message1 message = convert_bytes<Message1> (bytes);
   notify (message);
}

void dispatchMessage2(const vector<byte>& bytes)
{
   Message2 message = convert_bytes<Message2> (bytes);
   notify (message);
}

void dispatchMessage3(const vector<byte>& bytes)
{
   Message3 message = convert_bytes<Message3> (bytes);
   notify (message);
}
```

etc...

Register the functions.

```
registerMessageDispatcher(ID::Message1, dispatchMessage1);
registerMessageDispatcher(ID::Message2, dispatchMessage2);
registerMessageDispatcher(ID::Message3, dispatchMessage3);
```

Now, the code to deal with the message will be:

```
auto bytes = receive ();
Id id = get_id (bytes);
dispatchMessage(id, bytes);
```