# std::nested_exception and polymorphism - Is this the best that can be done?

Tags: c++, exception, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, nested-exceptions

`std::nested_exceptions` are nice when all you want to do is calling `what()`, but accessing the interface of other exception types gets ugly.

Let us suppose I have two exception classes which store some additional information:

```
/* CODE BLOCK 1 */
class ErrorI : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    ErrorI(int a_integer) : std::runtime_error{"ErrorI"}, integer{a_integer} {}
    int integer;
};

class ErrorD : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    ErrorD(double a_real) : std::runtime_error{"ErrorD"}, real{a_real} {}
    double real;
};
```

Without nested exceptions, we can access the member variables in the try/catch block:

```
/* CODE BLOCK 2 */
int main()
{
    try {
        /* do stuff */;
    }
    catch(const ErrorI& ee){
        std::cout << "  Value: " << ee.integer << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const ErrorD& ee){
        std::cout << "  Value: " << ee.real << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But if we want to unwrap a `std::nested_exception`, things are not so straightforward. We need to define a function which will be called recursively, which should look like this:

```
/* CODE BLOCK 3 */
void process_exception(const std::exception& e, int level=0) {
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        process_exception(e, level+1);
    }

    /* ... process the top-most (latest) exception ... */
}
```

<s>Unfortunately, for processing the top-most exception, we cannot use the try/catch syntax in Code Block 2: if we rethrow e, it will be truncated to an std::exception, and we will lose all the additional information.</s> EDIT: This is not true if std::rethrow_exception and std::exception_ptr are used.

So we're back to the problem of good-ole dynamic type-checking, with all that it entails (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451776/dynamic-cast-for-multiple-derived-classes) for example).

1. Derive all the exceptions from a common base class with the desired interface. This includes approaches like the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This is neat, but not good if the exception classes are provided by a external library.
2. Using dynamic_cast:

   ```
    /* CODE BLOCK 4 */
    if (auto p = dynamic_cast<ErrorI const*>(&e)) {
        std::cout << "  Value: " << p->integer << std::endl;
    }
    else if (auto p = dynamic_cast<ErrorD const*>(&e)) {
        std::cout << "  Value: " << p->real << std::endl;
    }
   ```
3. ???

My only option seems to resort to 2. I would love to hear if there is any other suggestion.

Comment: "if we rethrow e, it will be truncated to an std::exception": I think that is what [`std::exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) is for. You can pass it to [`std::rethrow_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_exception) to rethrow it without slicing.

Comment: I don't really see the slicing, are you saying the problem is that `process_exception` has to specify the exception type in the catch clause?

Comment: If you don't want to put multiple catch-clauses with all the different types you want to process in `process_exception`, you can still do something similar by specifying a type list like `type_list<ErrorI, ErrorD>` and provide an overload set like `void process(ErrorI const&); void process(ErrorD const&);` and have some metafunction which dispatches the nested exceptions via the type list to the overloads.

Comment: Duh :-D I had tried using std::make_exception_ptr which does slice. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `std::exception_ptr`, you might do something like:

```
void print_exception(const std::exception_ptr& eptr, int level =  0)
{
    try
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
    }
    catch (const ErrorI& e)
    {
        std::cerr << std::string(level, ' ') << "exception: " << e.what() << ": " << e.integer << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const ErrorD& e)
    {
        std::cerr << std::string(level, ' ') << "exception: " << e.what() << ": " << e.real << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << std::string(level, ' ') << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

// prints the explanatory string of an exception. If the exception is nested,
// recurses to print the explanatory of the exception it holds
void print_exception_rec(const std::exception_ptr& eptr, int level =  0)
{
    print_exception(eptr, level);
    try {
        try {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
        }
    } catch(const std::exception&) {
        print_exception_rec(std::current_exception(), level+1);
    } catch(...) {}
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d116d0c63ae8170)